# How to protect aluminum fence posts from weed trimmer?

Tags: fence

I assumed the manufacturers of the fencing would sell an optional sleeve to protect the power-coating on the posts from the repeated scraping of the trimmer cord, but they do not?  Does anyone have any ideas?  Is this even needed?
[image]

Comment: Stop hitting it with the weed whacker? ;)

Comment: [This trimmer](http://www.amazon.com/WG109-15-Inch-Electric-Telescoping-Adjustable/dp/B004SF8L0Y) has a [guard to protect flowers and gnomes](http://i.imgur.com/u4UAt.png), but nothing to protect fence posts.

Comment: Already have a trimmer with no guard.

Comment: Don't you have to hit it with the trimmer cord to trim the grass up on it?

Comment: You could buy a replacement [Universal Trimmer Guard](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&safe=active&q=weed+trimmer+guard&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&biw=1255&bih=683&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=4146132835970012005&sa=X&ei=meczUNSmN8viyAHM4oGACQ&ved=0CGwQ8wIwAA)

Answer (score 1):

Get a piece of approprietly sized PVC pipe or corragated plastic drain pipe.For a 4 inch post use pipe with at least a 4 inch inside diameter Cut it into 6-9 inchs long pieces. Slice the pieces so you have 1/2 of a piece of pipe. Bury the pipe about 3-6 inches into the ground  so it covers the base of the post. Fill the space between the pipe and the post with crushed stone.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that the fence posts are square.  I wondered about this.  Do they make square extruded PVC pipe?

Comment: It doesn't matter. You will have a small space from the curve in the pipe that you can fill in with crushed stone so that water won't collect in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found these.  I don't know how I found them or why I couldn't find them before.

http://www.rittenhouse.ca/asp/Product.asp?PG=9000536